# Integrating the product of two Gaussians with different dimensions

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, marginal-distribution

I'm relatively unfamiliar with sort of integration calculus, so apologies in advance for any notation issues.

Given parameters of some linear-regression model $\mathbf{a}=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$, and observation $x_n$. In my context, $a_1$ is known a priori and may be treated as a constant, so I'm looking to compute the marginal wrt the second two parameters, $(a_2,a_3)$, of the product of two Gaussian distributions. The Gaussians are of different dimensions (the left integrand term wrt the random variable $x_n$, but with mean $\mu$ a function of $\mathbf{a}$, and the right term wrt the random variable $(a_2,a_3)$).

$$
f(x_n)=\int \mathcal{N}_{x_{n}}(\mu(\mathbf{a}),r) \mathcal{N}_{(a_2,a_3)}(\mathbf{m},\Sigma) \; d(a_2,a_3)
$$

Now $\mu(\mathbf{a})=\mathbf{\psi}\cdot(a_1,a_2,a_3)$, where $\psi \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is some vector of constants. Given the values $a_1$, $r$, $\mathbf{m}\in\mathbb{R}^2$, and $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ are known a priori, is this analytically tractable?

I've tried using the following substitutions, but haven't made much progress.

\begin{align}
    \mathcal{N}_{x_{n}} &\propto \exp \left[ -\frac{1}{2r}(x_{n}-\mathbf{\psi}^T\mathbf{a})^2\right]\\
    \mathcal{N}_{(a_2,a_3)} &\propto \exp \left[-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left(\frac{(a_2-m_{a_2})^2}{\sigma_{a_2}^2} + \frac{(a_3-m_{a_3})^2}{\sigma_{a_3}^2} + \frac{2\rho(a_2-m_{a_2})(a_3-m_{a_3})}{\sigma_{a_2}\sigma_{a_3}}\right)\right]
\end{align}

EDIT: I note that I've checked similar questions, [Product of two Gaussian pdf's with different dimensions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245129/product-of-two-gaussian-pdfs-with-different-dimensions), but haven't found them very insightful in this particular situation.

EDIT(2): By *Jarle Tufto's* comment, I've denoted $x_{n}=\psi'\mathbf{a}+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon\sim\mathcal{N}_{x_{n}}(0,r)$, which has thus far yielded:

\begin{align}
    f(x_{n+1}|\mathbf{x_n}) &\propto
    \int \left(\mathbf{\psi}'\mathbf{a} + \epsilon\right)\cdot\mathcal{N}_{(a_2,a_3)}(\mathbf{m},\Sigma) \;  d(a_2,a_3) \\
    &= \int \left( \mathbf{\psi}'\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathcal{N}_{(a_2,a_3)}(\mathbf{m},\Sigma) \;  d(a_2,a_3)\right)  + \epsilon \\
&= \psi_1a_1+\int \left( (\psi_2,\psi_3)'(a_2,a_3)\cdot \mathcal{N}_{(a_2,a_3)}(\mathbf{m},\Sigma) \;  d(a_2,a_3)\right)  + \epsilon \\
&= \psi_1a_1+ (\psi_2,\psi_3)'\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{N}_{(a_2,a_3)}}[(a_2,a_3)] + \epsilon \\
&= \psi_1a_1+ (\psi_2,\psi_3)'\mathbf{m} + \epsilon \\
\end{align}

Is this correct? I'm a little sceptical, as $\Sigma$ is not included.

Comment: You can write $x_n$ as a linear combination $x_n = \psi^T \mathbf{a} + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim N(0,r)$ and independent of $\mathbf{a}$. Hence, $x_n$ is normally distributed with mean
$
E(x_n)=\psi^T \mathbf{m}
$
and variance
$
\operatorname{Var}(x_n) = \psi^T\Sigma \psi + r
$.

Comment: Viewing $x_n$ as a linear combination is interesting, but in your second sentence, the dimensions are inconsistent - $\psi\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbf{m}\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and there's a similar issue for the variance (refer to below first equation for dimensions). Note that the latter gaussian is bivariate wrt $(a_2,a_3)$ only.

Comment: The algebra needed to work with Normal density functions is not only tractable, it is particularly simple.  See our posts that refer to "completing the square."

Comment: Hi @whuber, I've updated the solution above. While it doesn't involve completing the square as you suggested, do you think this solution is adequate?